# Page Resizing Using GWT in IE (Internet Explorer)

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-8, tabpanel

Here's my scenario,

On my GWT page I have a TabPanel.  When it is populated with data it can become quite long.  The browser responds by lengthening the page.  This of course causes the brower's vertical scroll bar handle to shrink so that it reflects only the percentage of the page that is visible in the brower's window.

Now, if I programatically remove the TabPanel from the display, the GWT elements re-size smaller as you would expect, but the browser page stays the same size.  This leaves a large amount of unused white space at the bottom of the page that a user can scroll into.  And, the scroll bar handle stays small as well.

What I would like is for the browser page to shrink to fit the currently displayed content when I remove the tab panel.

This behavior only occurs in IE.  In firefox the page and scroll bar handle re-size properly.

Any ideas about how to address this?

Comment: This is a bug that is known to occur in IE 8 and below. You will notice it won't happen on IE 9, or any other standards-based browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all TabPanel or all your content in a GWT ScrollPanel.

The scroll panel can be the first element of RootPanel and stretch to cover the whole of Root Panel